# dlang call to function in other file fails

Tags: function, d

I'm testing to make calls to functions in other files using D code
My problem is that I receive errors I don't understand
in server.d

```
import std.stdio;
extern (D) void otherFunction();
main(){
otherFunction();}
```

and in client.d

```
import std.stdio;
void otherFunction(){ writeln("hello world");}
```

"dmd server.d" renders this output error

```html
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_D6server13otherFunctionFZv", referenced from:
      __Dmain in server.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Error: linker exited with status 1
```

Any ideas why I can't make the call?
Oh I'm on OS X 10.9 
And the call work as long as the function is in the same file as main()
/a

Answer (score -2, accepted):

D like C++ mangles all symbol names.
Unless the module name matches 1:1 (which you shouldn't do) then a symbol such as a function won't match up.

If you really really need this, switch over to `extern(C)` which work as you're expecting.

Comment: So what you Richard are saying is that D can't handle function calls where the functions are in different files, unless using extern(C) way.

Comment: This is wrong information. The symbol wasn't found, because he didn't tell DMD to compile the file. You have to give DMD all files that it has to compile.

Answer (score 4):

tried removing "extern ..." and 
added "import client; "
then compiled the two files together with "dmd server.d client.d"

Conclusion: To call functions in other files it is needed to import each file at the top and then compile all files in same line.

```
dmd server.d client.d
```

Comment: Yeah, this is common knowledge with the DMD compiler. You have to specify *ALL* files that you wish to compile.